# Order Price roll up in Account

Tags: lookup

I am trying to write a co  for the below scenario but could not get is working correctly..
Account has a lookup relationship with Or r object. (1:N relationship).
Or r has got a currency field. That field with same name is also present in account.My aim is : sum up all the count that are tagged to any particular account from all of the related or rs and display it on the Account page. I need to do it in a batch class but as I am new to batch apex not sure how to make it work without hitting govt limits. Kindly assist.

** tailed Scenario:** 
Hi sfdc_ninja, Thanks for your response.Here is what I am trying to do----  Account object has 1: N relation via look up with Or r_vod__c object..Every Or r_vod__c record has a Account_vod__c field that stores the account id information for that particular or r and has a   _Current_YTD_Sales__c field that stores the sales amount(currency field)...Suppose, 3 or r objects are there in the org with a single account id (i.e, in this case 1 account has 3 related or r records)and let say the currency amount values for those 3 or r records are 10, 20 and 30.So, I have show in Account object(10+20+30)=60 as total   _Current_YTD_Sales__c 's value. Please let me know if I can explain this scenario in a better way.

```
global class  BATCH_OR R_ACTIVATION_ ACTIVATION implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {                    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
        String query = 'select Id,  _Current_YTD_Sales__c,  _Last_YTD_Sales__c from Or r_vod__c where country_c='NE'';        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);   
    }      
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Or r_vod__c> scope) {       

        Double Sum2= 0.0; // this will sum up all of the realted or rs currency field tagged to a particluar acc

        Set<Id> accId= new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> ordId = new Set<Id>();
        List<Or r_vod__c> odList =new List<Or r_vod__c>();
        List<Or r_vod__c> ordrList= new List<Or r_vod__c>();
        List<Account> accList= new List<Account>();
        Map<Id, cimal> ordMapNA= new Map<Id, cimal>(); 
        Map<Id,Or r_vod__c> ordMap = new Map<Id,Or r_vod__c>(); 

        // Map to hold Or r - Account relationship

        Map<Id,Id> ord2accMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
        Map<Id, cimal> accMapNA1= new Map<Id, cimal>();
        Map<Id, cimal> accMapNA2= new Map<Id, cimal>();  

        for (Or r_vod__c ord : [select id,Account_vod__c,Status_vod__c, Or r_Status__c,
                                   _Current_YTD_Sales__c,  _Last_YTD_Sales__c 
                                 from Or r_vod__c 
                                 where Id in:odList]) {
                                     if (ord.  _Current_YTD_Sales__c!=0) {
                                         ordId.add(ord.id);
                                         ord2accMap.put(ord.id,ord.Account_vod__c);
                                         accId.add(ord2accMap.get(ord.id));
                                         ordMap.put(ord.Id,ord);
                                         ordrList.add(ord);
                                         system. bug('AWATIIIIIIIII'+ordrList);
                                     }
                                     /* Not required as accId is there in previous step
for (Account acc : [select id,  _Current_YTD_Sales__c,  _Last_YTD_Sales__c from Account where Id in : accId]) {
accId .add(acc.id); 
accList.add(acc);
}*/
                                 }

        for(Or r_vod__c Ordr: [select id,Account_vod__c,Status_vod__c, Or r_Status__c,
                                  _Current_YTD_Sales__c,  _Last_YTD_Sales__c 
                                from Or r_vod__c 
                                where Id in:ordId]) {
                                    if(!accMapNA1.ContainsKey(Ordr.Account_vod__c)) {
                                        accMapNA1.Put(Ordr.Account_vod__c,Ordr.  _Current_YTD_Sales__c); //If the Account Id does not exist then add it to Map
                                        system. bug('$$$$$$$$$$ Account Map If $$$$$$$$$'+accMapNA1);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Sum2 = accMapNA1.get(Ordr.Account_vod__c) + Ordr.  _Current_YTD_Sales__c; // Roll up co  for account
                                        system. bug('RACHAAAAAAAA'+Sum2);
                                        accMapNA1.Put(Ordr.Account_vod__c,Sum2);
                                        system. bug('%%%%%%%%%Account Map Else %%%%%%%%'+accMapNA1);
                                    }
                                }
        for(Id ids: accMapNA1.KeySet()) {
            Account accUpd= new Account (Id = ids);
            accUpd.  _Current_YTD_Sales__c= accMapNA1.get(ids);
            accList.add(accUpd);    
            system. bug('^^^^^^^^^update Acccount list^^^^^^^^'+accMapNA1);
        }
        update accList; 
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {   
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a master-detail relationship between order and account instead of a lookup? If so, you could use a roll-up summary field, no Apex required.

Comment: Lex- this are object created by Veeva having lookup relationship so master details look up is not possible. Only wasy is Apex coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are trying to accomplish this using batch apex, but I believe there is an easier way.  Anthony Victorio has an excellent blog and code to create a rollup on fields that are connected through a lookup relationship.  It allows you to emulate the rollup summary field available only for fields with MS relationships.

Take a look here

http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/

I have used this numerous times and it works wonderfully.

In your scenario it looks like you would just need to add a trigger on the order object, and have the rollup utility sum the amount of the orders to the account.

Assuming you use the class provided in the blog, then heres some code below that should get you going

**Your Trigger**

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

    AccountTriggerHelper helper = new ContactTriggerHelper();

    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete)){
        helper.rollupOrders(trigger.new);   
    }
}
```

**Your TriggerHelper Class**

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {

     public void rollupOrders(List<Account> newAccounts){

        list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
            new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('Count', 'Id', 'PFE_DE_Current_YTD_Sales__c')
        };    

        RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, newAccounts, 'Order_vod__c', 'Account_vod__c', 'Account', 'and country_c=\'NE\'\);         
    }
}
```

> **EDIT: How to accomplish using Batch job**

Few things general things from class to keep in mind.

1. You need to have the query in your start method query the accounts
   along with the related orders for that account.  This saves you a lot of trouble trying to query the relationship later and store it in a map like you are trying to do.
2. You also need to escape quotation when passing in criteria to a
   QueryLocator.  So in your query you have

   `'....and Country__c = 'NE''`, but it really should be `'....and
   Country__c = \'NE\''`

I came up with the code below.  I didn't know whether the 'country__c = 'NE' belonged on the account or the order, right now its on the account, but you can adjust it accordingly.  Also just added a debug statement as your finish method, as you don't have anything in the finish method.  Generally I use the finish method to do things like send emails alerting someone the batch was run or maybe to call another batch job.

Something like below should get you started.  I did this in a text editor and it hasn't been complied yet.

```
global class PFE_BATCH_ORDER_ACTIVATION_DEACTIVATION implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

     global final string query;

    global PFE_BATCH_ORDER_ACTIVATION_DEACTIVATION(){
        query = 'Select Id, PFE_DE_Current_YTD_Sales__c, (Select Id, Name, PFE_DE_Current_YTD_Sales__c From Order_vods__r)
                    From Account 
                    Where country__c = \'NE\'';
    } 

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
          return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope){
          List<Account> updateAccounts = new List<Account>();

          for(Sobject s : scope){
               Account a = (Account) s;
               double total = 0;
               for(Order_vod__c o : a.Order_vods__r){
                    total += o.PFE_DE_Current_YTD_Sales__c;
               }
               a.PFE_DE_Current_YTD_Sales__c = total;
               updateAccounts.add(a);
          }  

          try{
               update updateAccounts;
          }catch (Exception e) {    
               //your error trapping    
          }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
          System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN,'Batch Job Complete');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sfdc_ninja, Thanks for sharing this excellent link..However, I am not allowed to acheive this by trigger. So, I have to write a batch class only. Would be greateful If you can verify the class I tried to wrote.

Comment: Why are you not allowed?  Shouldn't you accomplish in the best way possible?

Comment: I can try to help you with a batch class, but a explanation in words of what you want to accomplish would be best then trying to sift through your code.  Do you just want this to run through all accounts and sum up the orders, or is their crtieria on the orders and/or accounts that needs to be considered?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to explain this above in Detailed Scenario: section. Kindly have a look. Trigger is not allowed as Order Object has got too many triggers already and it slows down the order submission process when users tried the offline version of Veeva CRM. Hence I am advised to run it once daily. I want to run this code for a particular count only..select Id,PFE_DE_Current_YTD_Sales__c,PFE_DE_Last_YTD_Sales__c from Order_vod__c where country_c='NE'';Pls note order does not have country fld but account has.

Comment: Hi sfdc_ninja, pls let me know if I need to elaborate the scenario more! Thanks

Comment: Added to the answer.  Hope that helps

Comment: Hi sfdc_ninja, thanks ..the line "for(Order_vod__c o : a.Order_vods__r)" is throwing some error..saying " Invalid field Order_vods__r for SObject Account at line 19 column 37".

Comment: I was just guessing on your relationship name.  You need to lookup the child relationship name for orders on Account.  If you use the IDE, you can go to the Schema, Go to the account object, expand child relationships and look for the relationship name for Orders

Comment: hey..thanks..It worked after I changed the relationship name..thank you very much...:)

Comment: Glad to hear it  :)